# How would you translate "grit" (personality trait) to Chinese?

Tags: translation

According to psychologist Angela Duckworth and colleagues, "grit" is defined as "perseverance and passion for long-term goals".

What would be the closest term for "grit" in Chinese?

Google gives me "sand" and "gravel" as its meaning.

砂砾 (shālì) = gravel
沙子 (shāzi) = sand
粗砂石 (cū shā shí) = coarse sandstone

Thanks, Nate
PS. I've also inquired Professor Duckworth and still waiting for her response.

Comment: see online dictionaries: http://www.iciba.com/grit 
<口>刚毅，坚韧； 勇气；
Fortitude, tenacity, courage, fortitude, perseverance, courage, 你不得不佩服她的勇气。
Linguee 我 們現在 知 道市民 亟 能 發 揮憐憫 、 **堅毅** 、 獻 身 和 犧牲的 精神。
bkrs:刚毅 fortitude;刚毅并不是他的性格 (mostly used as adjective, e.g.刚毅的性格)
坚韧:adjective 坚韧不拔的战士
勇气[courage; nerve] 勇往直前无所畏惧的气魄。
堅毅 firm; with inflexible will, unswerving determination

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 3):

> [毅力](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/5463/) (n)
>
> perserverance; willpower
>
> He has **grit** = 他有**毅力**

~

> [堅毅](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/57145/) (adj)
>
> be strong-willed and perseverant
>
> He is very **gritty** = 他很**堅毅**

~

> 堅毅 (n)
>
> strong will and perserverance
>
> This **grittiness** = 這份**堅毅**

Example sentence:

- 推行革命要有**毅力** - Carrying out the revolution requires **perseverance** (**grit**)
- **堅毅的**人能衝出困境，走向高峯 - **perseverant** (**gritty**) people can break out of  predicament and get to the top
- 成功全憑民眾的一股**毅力**/成功全憑民眾的一份**堅毅** - Success depends on the **perseverance** (**grittiness**) of the people

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should offer a sentence, because the translation will vary, depending on context.

grit **is** sand or gravel!

> Sense of "pluck, spirit, firmness of mind" first recorded American
>   English, 1808.

Duckworth's idiomatic definition is, well, not worth a duck, in my opinion.

Here grit is 毅力， willpower

如果他们颁发毅力金牌，卡伦应该站在领奖台上。
If they gave gold medals for grit, Karen would be right up there on the winners' podium.

but you might choose 勇气 courage or  坚韧不拔。

Comment: Thank you for the response.